# Ошибка git при push

Tags: git, github, git-commit, git-push, git-branch

Из-за того, что комитил с разных машин, что-то на путал с комитами. В итоге мне сейчас чтобы сделать push предлагается сделать pull request, но мне этого делать нельзя, потому что в сети старая версия проектов и получится куча конфликтов.
Как в такой ситуации лучше сделать?

```
git push origin main
To https://github.com/Voloodya/voteCollector.git
 ! [rejected]        main -> main (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/Voloodya/voteCollector.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

Comment: правильный способ - сделать pull, решить конфликты (+rebase возможно(, запушить. Неверный способ - сделать push  с ключиком --force, тогда в репозитории будут только те изменения, которые есть на Вашей машине. Но это нужно делать аккуратно, с бекапами

Comment: `предлагается сделать pull request` - это вы неправильно прочитали. Вам предлагается сделать pull, т.е. перед тем как свои изменения заливать в удаленный репозиторий, вам предлагается сначала получить оттуда новые изменения, которые были сделаны параллельно с вами. Если вы 100% уверенны, что в удаленном репозитории версия старая и вам нужно ее переписать своими локальными изменениями, то нужно делать `git push --force`

Comment: ну обычно делаю так save stash, git pull, apply stash, git commit push

Answer (score 0):

Написано же в консоли:

> hint: "git pull ..."!

То есть нужно сделать:

```
$ git pull
```